# How to change an element of a global array for all threads to see

Tags: c, pthreads

I am creating a program that has multiple threads using the same buffer. I create the buffer in global as `int *buffer` and dynamically declare the size in `main()` using `malloc`. The point of the buffer is for all threads to use this buffer, and I was wondering how each thread would modify a certain spot in the buffer so that all threads will see this change.

For example:

```
int *buffer;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    buffer = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));

}
```

Now I was wondering in the function that a pthread will do work in, how will a pthread modify a certain spot of `buffer` so that all other pthreads will see this change in the global array `buffer`.

In the function the pthreads use, would I just change the spot normally?

For example:

```
void *thread_work(void *unused){

    //beginning code

    buffer[0] = 2;

    //ending code

}
```

When I compile with this code, it compiles fine but I was wondering if all pthreads will now have `buffer[0]` set to 2.

P.S. I will be using mutex locks for synchronization so that will not be part of my question as I understand how to implement that.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how threads modify (and read) any global variable.

Comment: @DYZ okay thank you, your answer almost seems sarcastic but I'm assuming it actually is how you do it LOL. Sometimes I get confused with pointers and global variables but your straight forward answer is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special functions or operators for threads to use to perform operations on memory, whether local, threadlocal, or shared.  They just use the same syntax and techniques for that as they would if they were the only thread in the program.

But they *do* need to properly synchronize access to shared variables.  You say you're already familiar with that, so I won't go into detail, except to say that without synchronization, different threads indeed are not certain to see each others' writes.